# How to compare in RDLC

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I want a report. Report format is below:

```
Thana Good Removed NotFound

A     2     3        4

B      1     0       4

C      1     4       5

Total  4      7      13
```

I have Three type `GOOD`, `Removed`, `NotFound` on my db data. Format is below:

```
A GOOD
A GOOD
B NotFound
C Removed
B GOOD
```

How can I compare string? And after comparing how can I count the `A`  type `Good` is 2?

Comment: I added srss as a tag because rdlc is the format for Microsoft ReportViewer, which is similar to SRSS. Should make it easier to get answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Iif statements in your expression.

For example:

```
=Iif(Fields!Good.Value = 1, "GOOD IS 1", "GOOD IS NOT 1")
```

or

```
=Iif(Fields!Good.Value > Fields!Removed.Value, "Good is larger than removed", "Good is smaller or equal to removed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159673(SQL.90).aspx

In your case, if i understood correctly you would want to use Sum